# Azure function failing to start

Tags: .net, azure-functions

I have azure function which runs fine in one system, but failing in other. Below error gets logged

```
[2024-02-15T15:55:27.214Z] Exceeded language worker restart retry count for runtime:dotnet-isolated. Shutting down and proactively recycling the Functions Host to recover
[2024-02-15T15:56:27.081Z] Starting worker process failed
[2024-02-15T15:56:27.087Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Grpc: The operation has timed out.
[2024-02-15T15:56:27.110Z] Failed to start language worker process for runtime: (null). workerId:72524eee-6ff3-4410-a72e-a8be7a5ff8a1
[2024-02-15T15:56:27.198Z] You must install or update .NET to run this application.
[2024-02-15T15:56:27.201Z] App: C:\Users\veeduji\source\repos\Flooid\src\AzureFunctions\Flooid\DepositChargeProcessor\bin\Debug\net8.0\DepositChargeProcessor.dll
[2024-02-15T15:56:27.204Z] Architecture: x64
[2024-02-15T15:56:27.207Z] Framework: 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '8.0.1' (x64)
[2024-02-15T15:56:27.213Z] .NET location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\
[2024-02-15T15:56:27.216Z] The following frameworks were found:
[2024-02-15T15:56:27.221Z]   6.0.25 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
[2024-02-15T15:56:27.224Z]   7.0.14 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
[2024-02-15T15:56:27.226Z]   8.0.0 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
[2024-02-15T15:56:27.229Z] Learn more:
[2024-02-15T15:56:27.234Z]
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed
[2024-02-15T15:56:27.236Z] To install missing framework, download:
[2024-02-15T15:56:27.238Z]
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=8.0.1&arch=x64&rid=win-x64&os=win10
[2024-02-15T15:56:27.256Z] Host startup operation has been canceled
[2024-02-15T15:56:27.300Z] Failed to stop host instance '3a7db5ec-57d7-4806-9128-8d89abe3dae0'.
[2024-02-15T15:56:27.302Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: The host has not yet started.
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')
```

In system where i can run function has runtime 8.0.1, but system which fails obviously has 8.0.0
My doubt is, is Azure function runtime gets supported by 8.0.1? Can i make it run with 8.0.0?
Also a newbie here, please be kind.

Comment: There is no version specifically 8.0.1 in the Official site list - dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/8.0 Tell us which specific version from the list given in the site, you installed and trying with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work by installing runtime version 8.0.1

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my comment:-

*I tried a sample code using .NET 8.0 and ran it successfully locally and on the Azure Portal.*

**Code :**

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp100
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            return new OkObjectResult("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output :**

It ran successfully, as shown below.

```cs
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5504 Commit hash: N/A +f829589bca9exxxxxxxxxxxxx (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.28.3.21820

[2024-02-16T12:35:26.756Z] Found C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\source\repos\FunctionApp100\FunctionApp100\FunctionApp100.csproj. Using for user secrets file configuration.
[2024-02-16T12:35:32.181Z] Azure Functions .NET Worker (PID: 30948) initialized in debug mode. Waiting for debugger to attach...
[2024-02-16T12:35:32.256Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        Function1: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7107/api/Function1

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-02-16T12:35:37.556Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'.
[2024-02-16T12:36:18.136Z] Executing 'Functions.Function1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=dcaa580xxxxxxxxxxx)
[2024-02-16T12:36:18.651Z] C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.
[2024-02-16T12:36:18.652Z] Executing OkObjectResult, writing value of type 'System.String'.
[2024-02-16T12:36:18.804Z] Executed 'Functions.Function1' (Succeeded, Id=dcaa580xxxxxxxxxxx, Duration=726ms)
```

[image]

I received the following output in the browser using the get request URL mentioned above.

```
http://localhost:7107/api/Function1

Welcome to Azure Functions!
```

[image]

Then, I published my project to the function app, as shown below.

[image]

**Azure Portal :**

It ran successfully in the function app, as shown below.

[image]

Comment: As i mentioned, I'm trying from my system. Please read through my issue. I never mentioned I got issue with deploying to Azure. It works fine there.